# ValueError: Unable to infer channel dimension format

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

When training model with transformers, the following error occurs and I do not know how to resolve it (my input is torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])) :

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_23/2337200543.py in 
> 11 )
> 12 # begin training
> ---> 13 results = trainer.train()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in
> train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval,
> **kwargs)    1635             resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,    1636
> trial=trial,
> -> 1637             ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,    1638         )    1639
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in
> _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)    1870     1871             step = -1
> -> 1872             for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):    1873                 total_batched_samples += 1    1874
> if rng_to_sync:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py
> in **next**(self)
> 626                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
> 627                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
> --> 628             data = self._next_data()
> 629             self._num_yielded += 1
> 630             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py
> in _next_data(self)
> 669     def _next_data(self):
> 670         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
> --> 671         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
> 672         if self._pin_memory:
> 673             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py
> in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
> 56                 data = self.dataset.**getitems**(possibly_batched_index)
> 57             else:
> ---> 58                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
> 59         else:
> 60             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py
> in (.0)
> 56                 data = self.dataset.**getitems**(possibly_batched_index)
> 57             else:
> ---> 58                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
> 59         else:
> 60             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)    1763         """Can be used to index columns (by string names) or rows (by integer index or iterable of indices or
> bools)."""    1764         return self._getitem(
> -> 1765             key,    1766         )    1767
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in
> _getitem(self, key, decoded, **kwargs)    1748         pa_subtable = query_table(self._data, key, indices=self._indices if self._indices is
> not None else None)    1749         formatted_output = format_table(
> -> 1750             pa_subtable, key, formatter=formatter, format_columns=format_columns, output_all_columns=output_all_columns
> 1751         )    1752         return formatted_output
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py
> in format_table(table, key, formatter, format_columns,
> output_all_columns)
> 530     python_formatter = PythonFormatter(features=None)
> 531     if format_columns is None:
> --> 532         return formatter(pa_table, query_type=query_type)
> 533     elif query_type == "column":
> 534         if key in format_columns:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py
> in **call**(self, pa_table, query_type)
> 279     def **call**(self, pa_table: pa.Table, query_type: str) -> Union[RowFormat, ColumnFormat, BatchFormat]:
> 280         if query_type == "row":
> --> 281             return self.format_row(pa_table)
> 282         elif query_type == "column":
> 283             return self.format_column(pa_table)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py
> in format_row(self, pa_table)
> 385
> 386     def format_row(self, pa_table: pa.Table) -> dict:
> --> 387         formatted_batch = self.format_batch(pa_table)
> 388         try:
> 389             return _unnest(formatted_batch)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/formatting/formatting.py
> in format_batch(self, pa_table)
> 416         if self.decoded:
> 417             batch = self.python_features_decoder.decode_batch(batch)
> --> 418         return self.transform(batch)
> 419
> 420
>
> /tmp/ipykernel_23/3636630232.py in preprocess(batch)
> 3     inputs = feature_extractor(
> 4         batch['image'],
> ----> 5         return_tensors='pt'
> 6     )
> 7     # include the labels
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/image_processing_utils.py
> in **call**(self, images, **kwargs)
> 456     def **call**(self, images, **kwargs) -> BatchFeature:
> 457         """Preprocess an image or a batch of images."""
> --> 458         return self.preprocess(images, **kwargs)
> 459
> 460     def preprocess(self, images, **kwargs) -> BatchFeature:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/vit/image_processing_vit.py
> in preprocess(self, images, do_resize, size, resample, do_rescale,
> rescale_factor, do_normalize, image_mean, image_std, return_tensors,
> data_format, **kwargs)
> 260
> 261         if do_resize:
> --> 262             images = [self.resize(image=image, size=size_dict, resample=resample) for image in images]
> 263
> 264         if do_rescale:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/vit/image_processing_vit.py
> in (.0)
> 260
> 261         if do_resize:
> --> 262             images = [self.resize(image=image, size=size_dict, resample=resample) for image in images]
> 263
> 264         if do_rescale:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/vit/image_processing_vit.py
> in resize(self, image, size, resample, data_format, **kwargs)
> 125             raise ValueError(f"The `size` dictionary must contain the keys `height` and `width`. Got {size.keys()}")
> 126         return resize(
> --> 127             image, size=(size["height"], size["width"]), resample=resample, data_format=data_format, **kwargs
> 128         )
> 129
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/image_transforms.py
> in resize(image, size, resample, reducing_gap, data_format,
> return_numpy)
> 288     # For all transformations, we want to keep the same data format as the input image unless otherwise specified.
> 289     # The resized image from PIL will always have channels last, so find the input format first.
> --> 290     data_format = infer_channel_dimension_format(image) if data_format is None else data_format
> 291
> 292     # To maintain backwards compatibility with the resizing done in previous image feature extractors, we use
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/image_utils.py in
> infer_channel_dimension_format(image)
> 163     elif image.shape[last_dim] in (1, 3):
> 164         return ChannelDimension.LAST
> --> 165     raise ValueError("Unable to infer channel dimension format")
> 166
> 167
>
> ValueError: Unable to infer channel dimension format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using .png dataset for this training, once I converted to .jpg, all went well!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this discussion](https://huggingface.co/TahaDouaji/detr-doc-table-detection/discussions/5), you need to load your image using `image = Image.open("path_to_image").convert("RGB")` to fix this issue.